# Why do they use $\frac{1}{n}$ balls in this proof for closed sets?

Tags: real-analysis, proof-explanation

[image: n]

I can follow the proof all the way upto the fact that we need to show that no $B_\epsilon(x)$ lies completely in $T$ (thus the contradiction later).

If no ball lies completely in $T$, then it must spill over to the set $S$, hence
$\forall \epsilon >0, B_\epsilon (x) \cap S \neq \emptyset $.

But what's happening next. Is $x_n$ the $n$-th term in some sequence, contained in $S$? Suppose it is, then, are we saying this sequence converges to $x$, for $\epsilon = \frac{1}{n}$ Why? I'm very confused with the line:
"there is an element $x_n$ of $S$ in $B_{1/n}(x)$..." going forward, can someone clear this up?

Comment: Because $B_{1/n}(x) \cap S \neq \emptyset$, you can find $x_n \in B_{1/n}(x) \cap S$ and build the sequence $(x_n)_\mathbb{N}$.

Comment: $x_n$ is an element of $B_{1/n}(x) \cap S$. So $(x_n)_{n=1}^\infty$ is a sequence of points in $S$ that converges to $x$. This shows that $x$ is a limit point of $S$.

Comment: @dcolazin - my main issue is where this choice of $\frac{1}{n}$ comes from. The first statement is that $B_\epsilon (x) \cap S \neq \emptyset$, but why would that necessarily imply $B_1, B_{\frac{1}{2}}, ...,  B_{\frac{1}{n}} \cap S \neq \emptyset$ for $x_n \in B_{\frac{1}{n}}$ ?

Comment: @HonsTh Because $(\frac{1}{n})_\mathbb{N}$ is the simplest sequence that goes to $0$ when $n\rightarrow \infty$. For this proof you can use any sequence that goes to $0$. And because $\forall \varepsilon \ B_\varepsilon(x) \cap S \neq \emptyset$ then $\forall n \ B_\frac{1}{n}(x) \cap S \neq \emptyset$

Comment: Oh, I see. Thank you, that makes sense

Answer (score 1):

In such proofs, you can always use $\frac{1}{n}$ instead of $\varepsilon$, because of Archimedean property. If some property is satisfied by $\frac{1}{n}\forall n\in \mathbb N$ then choosing an $\varepsilon>0$, we can choose $\frac{1}{n}<\varepsilon$. Then, since the property is satisfied for all $\frac{1}{n}$ where $n\in\mathbb N$, it is satisfied by $\varepsilon$.

This trick has wide range of applications in probability, because it is used for discretising uncountable sets (note that countable summability is an axiom of probability).

**EDIT**
Let me expain line by line.

You understand the statement for $\varepsilon$, i.e. $\forall \varepsilon>0 B_\varepsilon (x)\cap S\neq \emptyset$. Since this statement holds for all positive $\varepsilon$, it particularly holds for $\frac{1}{n}\forall n\in\mathbb N$. That is what the next statement is saying.

Since, these sets are not null, in the next statement author is picking elements $x_n\in B_\frac{1}{n}(x)\cap S$. Since the distance between $x_n$ and $x$ goes to zero, $x$ is the limit the sequence of $x_n$'s.

Now, in the final statement author uses the fact that limit of sequences in closed sets, lie in closed sets.

Hope it helps:)

Comment: Thanks for your response - I can understand why if the property is satisfied by $\epsilon$ then if $ \epsilon > \frac{1}{n}$ then it is satisfied for $\frac{1}{n}$ too. But there is no such statement in the explanation - is it implicit? My issue is, how do we know that this property is satisfied for all $\frac{1}{n}, n \in \mathbb{N}$ ?

Comment: Note that $B_a(x)\subset B_b(x)\forall a<b$

Comment: So, its just implied that $\epsilon > \frac{1}{n}$ ?